# Android Development - EditText & ButtonTheme

Tags: android, button, android-edittext

I have a problem with my edittext and button.  When I put them in my xml and run it, I get this...

[image: This what it looks like]

[image: This is what my edittext should look like]

Can anyone help me get the second output?

Edit:

The second picture is what I see in Eclipse.  I feel like it has something to do with the Theme. Some say it is Ice Cream Sandwich that is the problem but my app is 2.2 however my phone is running 4.0

Comment: can you show us the coding part

Comment: There is no coding, I just dragged in a EditText and a Button and ran the app.  When I run it, instead of seeing the second output, I see the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is using the holo theme which was new in android4.0. So i think if you specify the android2.3 theme in AndroidManifest.xml, then the second editbox will be displayed.
Such as:

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme" ...../>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're compiling (and previewing in the xml editor) for Ice Cream Sandwich. The native UI that you have in the second example is (I believe) from Gingerbread. You can either set your version backwards, or apply the relevant theme in the manifest for this activity.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How to do this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml, I think you just need to set this property:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

To a value greater than or equal to 15.  Do a clean/build and see if that helps.  That will tell the phone to use ICS or JellyBean.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a background to your edittext like  android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_white"

where rounded_corner_white :

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/White" />

        <corners android:radius="18dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```